# PyQt5 installation on MacOS failing with Environment error

Tags: python, macos, pip, pyqt5, macos-mojave

```
pip3 install PyQt5
```

results in

```
Collecting PyQt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.14.2-5.14.2-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (43.1 MB)
Collecting PyQt5-sip<13,>=12.7
  Using cached PyQt5_sip-12.7.2-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_9_x86_64.whl (63 kB)
Installing collected packages: PyQt5-sip, PyQt5
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/pylupdate5'
```

Anybody an idea what causes this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this is caused by a previous installation of PyQt5 with Homebrew:

`pylupdate5` (and as it turns out also `pyuic5` and `pyrcc5`) is a link generated by Homebrew pointing to `../Cellar/pyqt/5.14.0/bin/`, which does not exists.

**Removing the links** in `/usr/local/bin` for `pylupdate5`, `pyuic5`, and `pyrcc5` **resolved the problem**:

`Successfully installed PyQt5-5.14.2 PyQt5-sip-12.7.2`

:-)